# Frequent BSOD on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bsod, windbg

Since about 3 weeks i'm getting frequent BSOD, when i try to analyze them with WINDBG it seems that the cause is always changing. I'm afraid i can't figure this out on my own.

[Link to dumps](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1x_vllJ2PJnJrXpcWjlGTmP1hSXJGphX-)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

These causes seem to be returning multiple times:

```
DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (d1)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If kernel debugger is available get stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: fffff4045de0f1a0, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000000, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
Arg4: fffff80281e1e6c3, address which referenced memory



MEMORY_MANAGEMENT (1a)
    # Any other values for parameter 1 must be individually examined.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000041792, A corrupt PTE has been detected. Parameter 2 contains the address of
    the PTE. Parameters 3/4 contain the low/high parts of the PTE.
Arg2: ffffa93ffab5e580
Arg3: 0000400000000000
Arg4: 0000000000000000



IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (a)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If a kernel debugger is available get the stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: ffffaaffff807f80, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000000, bitfield :
    bit 0 : value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
    bit 3 : value 0 = not an execute operation, 1 = execute operation (only on chips which support this level of status)
Arg4: fffff8064966e410, address which referenced memory



KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE (139)
A kernel component has corrupted a critical data structure.  The corruption
could potentially allow a malicious user to gain control of this machine.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A LIST_ENTRY has been corrupted (i.e. double remove).
Arg2: fffff803125eb760, Address of the trap frame for the exception that caused the bugcheck
Arg3: fffff803125eb6b8, Address of the exception record for the exception that caused the bugcheck
Arg4: 0000000000000000, Reserved
```

EDIT: I have Kaspersky free antivirus installed.

Comment: What security software do you have installed?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment.  [Driver Verifier](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/driver-verifier-tracking-down-a-mis-behaving/f5cb4faf-556b-4b6d-95b3-c48669e4c983) is helpful in a case like this,

Comment: "cause is always changing" this usually means a bad memory stick.

Comment: Not solution yet. Tried chkdsk and memtest86+ but nothing was found